# How to redirect to a specific part of a page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I want to redirect to a specific part of a page which has a specific id when using redirect(controller/view). Can you guys help me.

Comment: what have you done share some code?

Comment: Just reload the code of specific position with ajax.

Answer (score 3):

You can use #id_of_element with the URL you are constructing.

```
redirect('controller/view#id_of_your_html_element');
```

this will load the page to the specific location